# Huge selectbox divide in 2 selectboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.5

I have this function that I think shows the huge selectbox...

```
function loadChild() {  
    $configmodel = gbimport ( "listbingo.model.configuration" );
    $params = $configmodel->getParams ();   
    $adid = ( int ) JRequest::getVar ( 'adid', 0 );
    $parent = ( int ) JRequest::getVar ( 'catparentid', 0 );
    $selfid = ( int ) JRequest::getVar ( 'selfid', 0 ); 
    if (! $parent) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $catmodel = gbimport ( "listbingo.model.category" );
        //$children = $catmodel->getParentTreeForSelect(true, $parent);
        $cat_list = $catmodel->getParentTreeForSelect ( true, $parent );    
        $categories = array ();
        $categories [] = JHTML::_ ( 'select.option', '', JText::_ ( 'SELECT_CATEGORY' ), 'value', 'text' );
        foreach ( $cat_list as $cat ) { 
            $xtreename = str_replace ( ".", "", $cat->treename );
            $xtreename = str_replace ( "&nbsp;", "-", $xtreename );
            $xtreename = str_replace ( "<sup>|_</sup>", "", $xtreename );       
            if ($cat->children > 0) {       
                $categories [] = JHTML::_ ( 'select.optgroup', JText::_ ( $xtreename ), 'value', 'text' );
            } else {
                $categories [] = JHTML::_ ( 'select.option', $cat->value, JText::_ ( $xtreename ), 'value', 'text' );           
            }       
        }       
        if((int)$adid>0)
        {
            $disarray = array ('class' => 'inputbox required', 'onChange' => 'processSubcat(this.value)','disabled'=>'disabled');
        }
        else
        {
            $disarray = array ('class' => 'inputbox required', 'onChange' => 'processSubcat(this.value)');
        }                                   
        $subcats = JHTML::_ ( 'select.genericlist', $categories, 'scatid', $disarray, 'value', 'text', $selfid );           
        $view = $this->getView ( 'ajaxinput' );
        $view->setLayout ( 'subcat' );
        $view->assignRef ( 'subcats', $subcats );
        $view->assignRef ( 'adid', $adid );
        $view->assignRef ( 'selfid', $selfid );
        $view->display ();
    }
}
```

The selectbox look something like this:

```
<select name="scatid">
<optgroup label="June">
<option>2005</option>
<option>2006</option>
<option>2007</option>
<option>2008</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="July">
<option>2005</option>
<option>2006</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

it has hundreds of options (all the selctbox) and dozens of optgroups...

What I'm trying to achieve is show the optgroups in one selectbox... and the options for the selected optgroup in another selectbox...

Can somebody help me with this... I have no idea with what to start... I'm not to good in js/jquery...

I want it like this because there are too many options to choose and I have to scroll down a lot to find what I need...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery-ui-filter-select-widget](http://www.erichynds.com/blog/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) might help you out here.

It has all features as you mentioned in above description.

Here are the few [Demos on JQuery select widget](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/index.htm#filter)

Ex.

**HTML Code:**

```
<select id="example" name="example">
  <optgroup label="test">
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="foo">
        <option value="orange">Orange</option>
        <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
        <option value="black">Black</option>
    </optgroup>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#example").multiselect().multiselectfilter();;
});
```

Comment: jQuery UI is rather a large library for this request isn't it?